# Linear maps which exterior power preserves particular vector

Tags: linear-algebra, exterior-algebra

Is there any convenient way to describe all linear operators $A \colon V \to V$ whose exterior power $\Lambda^k A$ preserves some vector $v \in \Lambda^k V$ (not necessary decomposable)? $V$ is presumed to be finite dimensional.

For example, in the case $k = 1$ we could just take some basis $v, e_1, \ldots e_{\dim V - 1}$ and describe all such operators as operators with matrices whose first column equal to $(1,0,\ldots,0)^T$ in this basis.